# inotify_add_watch fails on /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate

Tags: c, inotify

I have used inotify in Linux, to get the event raised when ever the network interface link changes. whenever interface link changes, /sys/class/net/eth40/operstate/ file gets modified. But in the below code snippet even though the file is getting modified, read function is still in blocked state.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define FILE_TO_WATCH "/sys/class/net/eth40/operstate"
#define EVENT_SIZE (sizeof (struct inotify_event))
#define EVENT_BUFFER_LENGTH (1024 * EVENT_SIZE + NAME_MAX + 1)

void print_event(struct inotify_event *event) {

    int ret = 0;
    if (event->mask & IN_CREATE)
        printf("file created in directory\n");
    if (event->mask & IN_DELETE)
        printf("file deleted in directory\n");
    if (event->mask & IN_ACCESS)
        printf("file accessed\n");
    if (event->mask & IN_CLOSE)
        printf("file closed after reading or writing \n");
    if (event->mask & IN_OPEN)
        printf("file opened\n");

    if (event->len)
        printf("name: %s\n", event->name);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int notify_fd;
    int watch_fd;
    long input_len;
    char *ptr;
    char buffer[EVENT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
    struct inotify_event *event;

    notify_fd = inotify_init();
    if (notify_fd < 0) {
        perror("cannot init inotify");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("done1\n");
    watch_fd = inotify_add_watch(notify_fd,FILE_TO_WATCH,IN_ACCESS|IN_MODIFY);
    if (watch_fd < 0) {
        perror("cannot add file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("done2\n");
    while (1) {
        input_len = read(notify_fd, buffer, EVENT_BUFFER_LENGTH);
        if (input_len <= 0) {
            perror("error reading from inotify fd");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("done3\n");
        ptr = buffer;
        while (ptr < buffer + input_len) {
            event = (struct inotify_event *) ptr;
            print_event(event);
            ptr += sizeof (struct inotify_event) +event->len;
        }
    }
}
```

am'I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

/sys is not a regular file system, but a special in-memory file system called [sysfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs)

To quote a [kernel developer](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.file-systems/83641):

> inotify does not and will not work on sysfs.  Or procfs.  Or devpts. 
>   Or any number of network filesystems.  No matter how hard somebody
>   might wish it to work, that's simply not feasible.

For network link events you can use rt[netlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html), though stuff like this is hardly documented, here's an starting point example that will show you link (and a few other) events, you'll have to figure out which events/flags and similar that is relevant for your particular case.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>

#define ENTRY(x) {x, #x}
struct {
    unsigned flag;
    const char *name;
} ifi_flag_map[] = {
    ENTRY(IFF_UP),
    ENTRY(IFF_BROADCAST),
    ENTRY(IFF_DEBUG),
    ENTRY(IFF_LOOPBACK),
    ENTRY(IFF_POINTOPOINT),
    ENTRY(IFF_NOTRAILERS),
    ENTRY(IFF_RUNNING),
    ENTRY(IFF_NOARP),
    ENTRY(IFF_PROMISC),
    ENTRY(IFF_ALLMULTI),
    ENTRY(IFF_MASTER),
    ENTRY(IFF_SLAVE),
    ENTRY(IFF_MULTICAST),
    ENTRY(IFF_PORTSEL),
    ENTRY(IFF_AUTOMEDIA),
    ENTRY(IFF_DYNAMIC),
    ENTRY(IFF_LOWER_UP),
    ENTRY(IFF_DORMANT),
    ENTRY(IFF_ECHO),
};
struct {
    unsigned type;
    const char *name;
} nlmrt_type_map[] = {
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWLINK ),
    ENTRY(RTM_DELLINK),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETLINK),
    ENTRY(RTM_SETLINK),
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWADDR ),
    ENTRY(RTM_DELADDR),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETADDR),
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWROUTE    ),
    ENTRY(RTM_DELROUTE),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETROUTE),
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWNEIGH    ),
    ENTRY(RTM_DELNEIGH),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETNEIGH),
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWRULE ),
    ENTRY(RTM_DELRULE),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETRULE),
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWQDISC    ),
    ENTRY(RTM_DELQDISC),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETQDISC),
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWTCLASS   ),
    ENTRY(RTM_DELTCLASS),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETTCLASS),
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWTFILTER  ),
    ENTRY(RTM_DELTFILTER),
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWACTION   ),
    ENTRY(RTM_DELACTION),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETACTION),
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWPREFIX   ),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETMULTICAST ),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETANYCAST  ),
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWNEIGHTBL ),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETNEIGHTBL ),
    ENTRY(RTM_SETNEIGHTBL),
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWNDUSEROPT ),
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWADDRLABEL ),
    ENTRY(RTM_DELADDRLABEL),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETADDRLABEL),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETDCB ),
    ENTRY(RTM_SETDCB),
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWNETCONF ),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETNETCONF ),
    ENTRY(RTM_NEWMDB ),
    ENTRY(RTM_DELMDB ),
    ENTRY(RTM_GETMDB ),
};

void print_type(unsigned type)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof nlmrt_type_map/sizeof nlmrt_type_map[0]; i++) {
        if (type == nlmrt_type_map[i].type) {
            printf("\t\tMsg Type: %s\n", nlmrt_type_map[i].name);
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("\t\tMsg Type: unknown(%d)\n", type);
}
void print_flags(unsigned flags, unsigned change)
{
    size_t i;

    printf("\t\tflags: ");

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof ifi_flag_map/sizeof ifi_flag_map[0]; i++) {
        if (flags & ifi_flag_map[i].flag) {
            if (change & ifi_flag_map[i].flag) {
                printf("%s(C) ", ifi_flag_map[i].name);
            } else {
                printf("%s ", ifi_flag_map[i].name);
            }
        }
    }
    puts("");
}
oid read_msg(int fd)
{
    int len;
    char buf[4096];
    struct iovec iov = { buf, sizeof(buf) };
    struct sockaddr_nl sa;
    struct msghdr msg = { (void *)&sa, sizeof(sa), &iov, 1, NULL, 0, 0 };
    struct nlmsghdr *nh;

    len = recvmsg(fd, &msg, 0);
    if(len == -1) {
        perror("recvmsg");
        return;
    }

    for (nh = (struct nlmsghdr *) buf; NLMSG_OK (nh, len);
         nh = NLMSG_NEXT (nh, len)) {
         struct ifinfomsg *ifimsg;
        /* The end of multipart message. */
         printf("netlink message: len = %u, type = %u, flags = 0x%X, seq = %u, pid = %u\n",
            nh->nlmsg_len,
            nh->nlmsg_type,
            nh->nlmsg_flags,
            nh->nlmsg_seq,
            nh->nlmsg_pid);

        if (nh->nlmsg_type == NLMSG_DONE)
            return;

       if (nh->nlmsg_type == NLMSG_ERROR) {
            continue;
       }

       ifimsg = NLMSG_DATA(nh);
       printf("\tifi_family = %u, ifi_type = %u, ifi_index = %u, ifi_flags = 0x%X, ifi_change = 0x%X\n",
               ifimsg->ifi_family ,
               ifimsg->ifi_type ,
               ifimsg->ifi_index ,
               ifimsg->ifi_flags ,
               ifimsg->ifi_change);
       print_type(nh->nlmsg_type);
       print_flags(ifimsg->ifi_flags, ifimsg->ifi_change);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_nl sa;
    int fd;

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    sa.nl_groups = RTMGRP_LINK | RTMGRP_IPV4_IFADDR;

    fd = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);
    if(fd == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }

    if(bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(sa)) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        return 1;
    }
    for(;;) {
        read_msg(fd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you please suggest me any other method to monitor network link events on a NIC port.

Comment: is there any method to implement network link events in windows in c?

Comment: @MujtabaMohd Probably. You could ask a new question about after you've checked whether that is already asked here on stackoverflow or have checked the MSDN docs for an easy solution.