# How to efficiently monitor when Ethernet is plugged/unplugged on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, hardware

My end goal is to create a script that runs on startup that turns off wifi when an Ethernet cable is plugged in, and vice-versa. This is the script I've created so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
File=/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier
function toggle {
        if grep -q 1 "$File"; then
                echo "Yes"
        else
                echo "No"
        fi
}

toggle # Once on startup
while inotifywait -q $File; do
        toggle
done
```

I've confirmed that plugging in and unplugging the Ethernet cable does change `/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier`, but for some reason, absolutely nothing happens when it's updated. I tested if the command was detecting changes at all by changing File to be a temporary file in my home directory called "test.txt". Whenever I accessed the file, changed its contents etc., the script continued as expected. I tried overwriting the file by doing `echo '1' > test.txt`, which worked. Deleting the file resulted in an error and the script terminating, but at least it registered a response.

I could just set the script to execute every second, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Did you try with `function toggle () {`  ?

Comment: My suspicion is that `inotifywait` only works on normal files and directories, and not on device files that basically generate themselves when you read from them.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398225/168016) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26674239/2214695), `inotify` may not work on `/sys` files.

An alternative is to use `ip monitor` and check for `state UP` or `state DOWN` strings:

```
ip monitor link dev eth0 | awk '/state DOWN/{print "No"} /state UP/{print "Yes"}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I tried running that command you gave me, and nothing happened when I plugged/unplugged my ethernet cable. I tried changing both occurrences of "print" to "echo", but still nothing. Tried running as sudo; still nothing.