# Watch module /sys/module/uvcvideo/refcnt for changes (to trigger action on webcam use)

Tags: python, linux, bash, inotifywait

I would like to switch an On Air sign at my work-from-home office when my webcam is on.

Detecting whether the webcam is on can easily be done via

```
cat /sys/module/uvcvideo/refcnt
```

if it outputs 0 no app is using the webcam, otherwise it is.

I already have a Wifi plug which can be switched using a HTTP GET request.

My only question is: Do I have to poll the output of the above command regularly, or can I get notified in some Bash, Python or PHP script from the kernel?

The idea would be to not generate unnessary system load by polling - or doesn't that matter?

I already tried `inotifywait` but it does not seem to notice changes on the above pseudo file.

Comment: The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672414/inotify-add-watch-fails-on-sys-class-net-eth0-operstate claims that `inotify` won't work with `/sys` files - but it's 6 years old, so the answer may have changed.  However, polling maybe twice per second will put no significant load on the system, and the latency would hardly be noticeable.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I tried inotify, but it is not working with /sys/module/uvcvideo/refcnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on jasonharpers answer I implemented it as a daemon that uses polling

https://github.com/amenk/OnAirDaemon